# Clarity Errors: CORS Policy Violations and HTTP 503

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, microsoft-clarity

I followed the [official setup guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/clarity/google-tag-manager) to add Microsoft Clarity on my website using Google Tag Manager. I am getting CORS policy violation errors and 503 errors on my website. Some outbound requests to Clarity are failing. Is this a misconfiguration on my side? If yes, how can I fix this?

**Error Log**

```
14:47:17.201 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.clarity.ms/eus2/collect' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
14:47:17.203 www.clarity.ms/eus2/collect:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
14:47:57.731 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.clarity.ms/eus2/collect' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
14:47:57.734 www.clarity.ms/eus2/collect:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
14:48:03.072 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.clarity.ms/eus2/collect' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
14:48:03.073 www.clarity.ms/eus2/collect:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
14:48:03.551 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.clarity.ms/eus2/collect' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
14:48:03.552 www.clarity.ms/eus2/collect:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
14:48:04.504 www.clarity.ms/eus2/collect:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 ()
```

**Screenshot**

[image]